# How to debug sudden PageView drop in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We are a video-only news portal. Recently with no production-changes, our PV (in GA) number has dropped by ~ 75%+. Interestingly one of our key metric - Video Views (measured by Brightcove, our CMS) didn't indicate any such catastrophe.

Data from Nielsen and internal ad inventory also seem to disagree with GA.

What's the best possible way to debug this ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check if the GA code is in all pages.